# Pessimistic locking with Hibernate and DB2 (and Derby)?

Tags: hibernate, spring, locking, db2

Having the following code:

```
@Transactional // Spring annotation
public void doStuffWithPayments(...) {
  List payments = getCurrentSession().createQuery("select distinct p from Payment p .....")
      .setLockMode("p", LockMode.UPGRADE)
      .list();
  do_stuff(); // Takes an extended amount of time
  updatePayments(payments);
}
```

...generates sql like:

```
select ...... from Payment where .....  for read only with rs
```

Two concurrent threads enter the method trying to access the same db record. Thread 1 enters a short time before thread 2. I would like thread 2 to be forced to wait at the ".list()" until thread 1 leaves the transaction scope and the transactions is committed.

Is this possible?

**EDIT** (after comment):
Tried

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

but both threads still get pass the db read operation.

At the final db write a deadlock in the database occurs.

**EDIT2**
I get the same behaviour using Derby.

Also tried to set lock as proposed:

```
getCurrentSession().refresh(object, LockMode.UPGRADE);
```

Thread 2 still gets through and reads the object from db...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to lock an object:

```
if (object != null && getSession().getCurrentLockMode(object) != LockMode.UPGRADE) {
    getSession().refresh(object, LockMode.UPGRADE);
}
```

SERIALIZABLE isolation level is the highest level of isolation and it's very expensive, since all of the transactions will be executed serially. So you would want to make sure that you really need it before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `isolation=SERIALIZABLE` into the annotation.

Comment: Huh, looks very strange. I don't see any problem in the code. The transaction is not read-only, right? Are you completely sure that you cannot use optimistic locks?

Answer (score 0):

See here:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2356502

It suggests subclassing the DerbyDialect and overriding the getForUpdateString() method.

This works for me, albeit with an old version of Hibernate (3.3.2.GA).